# How to make a rule for the complex conjugation of a symbol?

Tags: syntax, rule

Consider some symbols `piplus`, `piminus`, `eta`. Let us assume that they appear as conjugated, e.g., `Conjugate[piplus]`. Could you please tell me whether it is possible to define a rule which would automatically replace `Conjugate[piplus]` with `piminus`, and `Conjugate[piminus]` with `piplus`, and `Conjugate[eta]` with `eta`?

Say, I may use

```
rule := {Conjugate[piplus] :> piminus, Conjugate[piminus] -> piplus}
Conjugate[piplus] + Conjugate[piminus] /. Evaluate[rule]
```

But I do not want to always add  `/. Evaluate[rule]` in the given notebook.

Comment: Use multiple [`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) definitions, such as: `piminus /: Conjugate[piminus] := piplus`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the rules once and globally using multiple [`TagSetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) definitions:

```
piminus /: Conjugate[piminus] := piplus
piplus /: Conjugate[piplus] := piminus
eta /: Conjugate[eta] := eta

Conjugate[piplus] + 2 Conjugate[piminus] + Conjugate[eta]

(* Out: eta + piminus + 2 piplus *)
```